# Invoke ActionBar's Up button press from code

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-testing

I am writing an Android app with ActionBar enabled. In my case I use ActionBarSherlock to provide compatibility, but I think it doesn't matter in this case.

I have an Up button displaying at the left of ActionBar in my Activity. It appears after a call to `setHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and it leads to the HomeActivity.

I want to write a test case which checks that Up button press leads to that HomeActivity.
I am using Robotium to write tests on UI side so I can check the class of the current Activity by following assertion `solo.assertCurrentActivity(HomeActivity.class);`
But I have not found a way to invoke a press on an Up button.

I've tried `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.R.id.home))` and `getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(solo.getCurrentActivity(), android.R.id.home, 0);` but none of them works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a workaround myself, so posting it here in case anybody will need this.
This code worked for me:

```
public static void clickOnUpActionBarButton(Activity activity) {
        ActionMenuItem logoNavItem = new ActionMenuItem(activity, 0, android.R.id.home, 0, 0, "");
        ActionBarSherlockCompat absc = (ActionBarSherlockCompat) UiTestUtils.invokePrivateMethodWithoutParameters(
                SherlockFragmentActivity.class, "getSherlock", activity);
        absc.onMenuItemSelected(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, logoNavItem);
    }
```

First you need to obtain ActionBarSherlockCompat object by calling `getSherlock()` on SherlockFragmentActivity. This method is protected, so I used Reflection API to call it:

```
public static Object invokePrivateMethodWithoutParameters(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Object receiver) {
        Method method = null;
        try {
            method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, (Class<?>[]) null);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getClass().getName() + ": " + methodName);
        }

        if (method != null) {
            method.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                return method.invoke(receiver, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You need to pass `solo.getCurrentActivity()` to my `clickOnUpActionBarButton(Activity activity)` method and Up button will be pressed.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is perfectly working for me, but unfortunately not for the **latest sdk** versions! I got an error, because ActionBarSherlockNative could not be casted to ActionBarSherlockCompat.

So I have made the following simple workaround that should work on any device:

```
public static void clickOnUpActionBarButton(Solo solo) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 15) {
        Activity activity = solo.getCurrentActivity();

        ActionMenuItem logoNavItem = new ActionMenuItem(activity, 0, android.R.id.home, 0, 0, "");
        ActionBarSherlockCompat absc = (ActionBarSherlockCompat) UiTestUtils.invokePrivateMethodWithoutParameters(
                SherlockFragmentActivity.class, "getSherlock", activity);
        absc.onMenuItemSelected(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, logoNavItem);
    } else { // Working on latest sdk versions (above 4.0)
        solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    }
}
```

Tested it on a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.1 (API 17)

Comment: @atermenji I have to thank you too, because your approach really helped me out! This issue occurred to me while I was testing with two different devices (one with API < 15 and one above).

Comment: you can also look at the Robotium source code, it has method to click on Home button on Android 4.0+ (I've added it some time ago). Also you can check my extension of Robotium for testing apps with ActionBarSherlock on Gingerbread (https://github.com/atermenji/robotium-actionbarsherlock/)

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I changed it from  `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.R.id.home))` to  **`solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton()`**